# bash regexp "find anything between last slash and dot"

Tags: regex, bash

the source string is a path, let's say

/home/test/test/`filename`.ext

I need to match `filename` from path and catch it in a BASH_REMATCH

I've tried hundred of figures, it really makes my eyes water, the closest is

```
/[^/]*.$
```

but it only match filename.ext

and `\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.`

but it match /filename.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
s='/home/test/test/filename.ext'
[[ "$s" =~ /([^./]+)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
filename
```

Comment: i seems that I was close, my real problem was ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} and ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} which are quite different.ty

Answer (score 0):

You should use the end anchor

```
([^/]+)\.[^/.]+$
```

Then filename is in group 1.